# Showing that $45083$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

The question is:

Does $\;x^2 + 10x + 15 = 0\pmod{45083}\;$ have a solution?

I can rearrange this to $(x+5)^2 = 10\pmod {45083} \;$ so if I can show that $10$ has a  square root mod 45083, I'm done.

If I can show that $45083$ is prime then I can use Legendre symbols and the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity to complete the question.

I don't know how to show that 45083 is prime. I don't think Wilson's theorem is practical. Trial division takes a very long time.

Maybe there is another way?

Comment: If you don't have to show some work (divisions, some sieve...) you can take a peek here:http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt . If you *do have* to show some work then...well, then sad for you: you'll have to do a lot of work, this way or another.

Comment: You may be able to cut the work a little, since 45083 is a [safe prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) (i.e., 22541 is a [Sophie Germain prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime). If you first show that 22541 is a prime, then you can use the [Pocklington primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test) to show that 45083 is a prime. The amount of work saved is not great, however. 22540 is quite easy to factor, however; it has quite small prime factors. So maybe you can prove that 22541 is prime using Pocklington–Lehmer.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed $\,45,083\,$ is a prime, so by the QRT:

$$\left(\frac{10}{45083}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{45083}\right)\left(\frac{5}{45083}\right)\stackrel{45083\neq\pm 1\pmod 8}=-\left(\frac{3}5\right)=-(-1)=1$$

Comment: Have you considered that the problem might be that you have made *no attempt to answer the question*?

Comment: Well, everytime I get a downvote I do expect to have some remark, explanation, etc. When there's nothing not always I guess the downvoter's intentions. Now, I did try to address the OP's question in my comments *and* continued from there.

Comment: That depends what is the question. Is it whether 10 is a square residue mod 45083? He answered that. Is it whether there is a short proof by hand that 45083 is prime? Well, he did not answer that. But see his comment to the question.

Comment: I see no evidence of *serial* downvoting, though. At least not in your most recent answers.

Comment: There were 3 downvotes in the last hours, @HaraldHanche-Olsen, though in the meantime one already disappeared. The other one left, besides the above, is in the thread "Why $\,9<\sqrt{89}<10"\,$

Comment: NO worries, though: things like this happen to many (and as far as I remember I was told sometime ago, even to most) of us here and there. Nothing to put a lot of attention to, in particular because the system automatically "gives" you back your points after a serial downvoting (once, I and other use, whose name I can't remember right now, got some 60-70 points down in 1-2 days. The system put them back after a while).